# Upload images to server with IOS-Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, http-post, image-uploading

I am making an app with which you can upload images to a server (It's in PHP 5.2).

First to raise the image did in the time you click the button was up from the app and showed a alertview with a loading bar , but took too long .

I have now changed so that when at up button from the app , the body of the http request , is stored in the database and then when navigating to a view controller rise is activated from the background asynchronously , so the user does not waste time .

The problem is that when saving to the database and then re- read , the POST request does not work properly and does not send me the body of the request

I do not know if this is the best way to do this or are there other better and more efficient .

I leave you an example of my code have if correct :

```
//Aqui genero el body de la peticion
func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: String?, filePathKey: String, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String, nameParam: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData()
    let mimetype = "image/jpg"
    let nombreImagen = obtenerNombreImagen()

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(nameParam)\"\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendString("\(cadenaParametros)\r\n")

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey)\"; filename=\"\(nombreImagen)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendData(imageDataKey)
    body.appendString("\r\n")

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body
}

func subirImagen() {
    if (myImageView.image != nil) {
        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 1)

        if(imageData == nil) {
            return
        }

        let body: NSData = self.createBodyWithParameters(paramString, filePathKey: "imagen", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary, nameParam: "param_img")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
            GestorDB.uploadFiles("Imagen", ruta: stringUrl, parametros: paramString, body: body, tipoPeticion: "POST", respuesta: "", estado: 0)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                progressAlert.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(-1, animated: true)
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message:
                    "Imagen añadida correctamente", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("volver", sender: self)
                }))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }
}

/*Clase gestorDb*/
//El campo de la tabla donde se guarda el body es tipo TEXT
class func uploadFiles(nombre: String, ruta: String, parametros: String, body: NSData, tipoPeticion: String, respuesta: String, estado: Int) -> Bool {
    let ubicacionDB = self.obtenerRutaDB()
    let database = FMDatabase(path: ubicacionDB as String)
    if !database.open() {
        return false
    }
    else {
        let sentenciaSql = "INSERT INTO archivo(nombre_archivo, ruta_archivo, parametros, body, tipo_peticion, respuesta, estado) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        if !database.executeUpdate(sentenciaSql, withArgumentsInArray: [nombre, ruta, parametros, body, tipoPeticion, respuesta, estado]) {
            database.close()
            return false
        }
        else {
            //print("INSERT CORRECT")
            return true
        }
    }
}
//Obtengo los datos
class func getFilesToUpload() -> FMResultSet {
    let ubicacionDB = self.obtenerRutaDB()
    let database = FMDatabase(path: ubicacionDB as String)
    if !database.open() {
        //print("No se puede abrir la bbdd")
    }
    let sentenciaSql = "SELECT * FROM archivo WHERE estado = 0"
    let results:FMResultSet? = database.executeQuery(sentenciaSql, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    return results!
}

/*ViewController*/
//Aqui obtengo losd atos de peticion guardadas no enviadas y las envio
if AppDelegate().isConnectedToNetwork() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        if GestorDB.getFilesToUpload().next() == true {
            let resultadoSql = GestorDB.getFilesToUpload()
            while resultadoSql.next() == true {
                let idArchivo: Int = Int(resultadoSql.intForColumn("id_archivo")) // .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
                let rutaArchivo  = resultadoSql.stringForColumn("ruta_archivo").stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
                let parametros  = resultadoSql.stringForColumn("parametros").stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
                var body  = resultadoSql.dataForColumn("body")//.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

                if body == nil {
                    body = NSData()
                }

                AppDelegate().uploadFile(body, stringUrl: rutaArchivo, parametros: parametros, idArchivo: idArchivo)
            }
        }
        else {
            //print("NOOO")
        }
    }
}


/*AppDelegate*/
func uploadFile(body: NSData, stringUrl: String, parametros: String, idArchivo: Int) {
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: stringUrl)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    let boundary = self.generateBoundaryString()

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = body

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        print("*** error = \(error)")
        print("**** data = \(data)")
        print("***** request = \(request)")
        print("****** response = \(response)")
        print("******* response data = \(responseString!)")//Me devuelve vacio

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            GestorDB.updateEstadoFiles(idArchivo)//Aqui solo cambio el estado a 1
        })
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Instead of storing it in DB, may I suggest you to create a nsurlsession upload task with background configuration?

Comment: Can you show me an example?? thank you @KhanXc